# Multiplying 2D matrices to get a 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two matrices A and B of dimensions (n_m, n_u) and (n_m, n). I want a 3D matrix with dimensions (n, n_m, n_u) such that the first column of B is multiplied (element-wise) with every column of A and the second column of B forms the next element in the 3D axis by doing the same, and so on.

suppose I have -

```
A = |1 2 3|
    |4 5 6|

B = |1 2|
    |3 4| 

The new matrix should be - 
C = |1   2  3| |2   4  6|
    |12 15 18| |16 20 24| 
C is 3D.
```

Comment: post your minimal coding efforts

Comment: Id suggest using `broadcasting` to get a (n_m, n_u, n) array first.  That should be easier to visualize.  Why put the last dim of `B` first, if you don't have to?  Also make `B` something like (2,4) shape to more clearly distinguish `n` from `n_m`

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,ik->kij', A, B)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [42]: a=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3); b=np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
```

Making `a` (2,1,3), and `b` (2,2,1), broadcasts their product to (2,2,3):

```
In [44]: a[:,None,:] * b[:,:,None]
Out[44]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  4,  6]],

       [[12, 15, 18],
        [16, 20, 24]]])
```

Changing `b` to be (2,4) shape

```
In [45]: a=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3); b=np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,4)

In [46]: a,b
Out[46]: 
(array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]]))

In [47]: a[:,None,:] * b[:,:,None]
Out[47]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 3,  6,  9],
        [ 4,  8, 12]],

       [[20, 25, 30],
        [24, 30, 36],
        [28, 35, 42],
        [32, 40, 48]]])
```

results in a (2,4,3) 3d array.

That could be transposed to a (4,2,3), but I don't think that's what your `C` implies.

```
In [48]: (a[:,None,:] * b[:,:,None]).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [20, 25, 30]],

       [[ 2,  4,  6],
        [24, 30, 36]],

       [[ 3,  6,  9],
        [28, 35, 42]],

       [[ 4,  8, 12],
        [32, 40, 48]]])
```

Trying the tranpose on the (2,2):

```
In [49]: a=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3); b=np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)

In [50]: (a[:,None,:] * b[:,:,None]).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[50]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [12, 15, 18]],

       [[ 2,  4,  6],
        [16, 20, 24]]])
```